# How do I reset the title in an HTML page, without reloading?

Tags: jquery, html, properties

I am trying to reset the title of the page in JQuery, without having to refresh it.  Every place I have looked allows me to use either:

`$('title').text('foo');`

OR

`$(document).attr('title', 'foo2');`

Which [apparently] needs a refresh to work properly.  I am loading information into a div in the main page and never needing to refresh the page.  Does anyone have any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: FYI, jQuery functions on the DOM (client side), it does NOT need a refresh **ever** for something to take place.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not much to do with jquery, except for when (ie handling some event) you decide to change the page title: `document.title = 'something';`

Comment: This only works if the page gets refreshed.  I am not refreshing the browser page, only a div within the page itself.

Answer (score 4):

can't you just use `document.title = "Something new";`?

Comment: Apparently 80% of jQuery users don't now JavaScript :-P

Comment: Yeah. Let's not think that jquery is a language ;p

Comment: It worked.  Thanks again ultimatebuster.  I really appreciate it.I am very sorry that I do not measure up to your standards of javascript as I am very new to this.  It's not like I "now" everything.  (Hey at least I can speak in whole sentences and not make silly grammatical errors right?)

Answer (score 1):

yes I am agree with @sidyll Apparently 80% of jQuery users don't now JavaScript so sometime try javascript concepts also.

but you can do with jquery as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#changeTitle').click(function(){
        $('title').html('New title');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Not really an answer though :)